# Vectorisation of MATLAB code

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I'm trying to vectorise the following MATLAB code to improve performance:

```
for IX = 2:NSCX
    for IY = 2:NSCY
        for IC = 1:Nc

                duplicate = 0;
                for IK = 1:IA(IX-1,IY-1,1)
                    if IA(IX-1,IY-1,IK+1) == IC
                        duplicate = 1;
                    end
                end
                if duplicate == 0
                    IA(IX-1,IY-1,1) = IA(IX-1,IY-1,1)+1;
                    IA(IX-1,IY-1,IA(IX-1,IY-1,1)+1) = IC;
                end
            end
        end
    end
end
```

IA is a 3-dimensional matrix (size(IA) = NSCX NSCY 9). Can anyone help with this. Thanks.

Comment: you mean code `vectorization`... also what are `Nc`, `IA` ?

Comment: So you think the code should be vectorised instead of parallelised? Nc is an integer, lets say Nc = 1000. For the example code above size(IA) = 250 250 9, so assume some 3 dimensional matrix. IA only contains integers. Is that enough information?

Comment: You say that IC is a cell, but treat it like a normal variable. Which one is correct? Also you do not have *integers*, but *doubles*, since you have not done a definition like `a = int64(5)`.

Comment: Sorry, my description wasn't clear. By cell I'm not referring to a cell array but cells of some discretised domain. IA is a normal variable. Also, you are right they aren't strictly integers. By integers I mean IA contains the cell index.

Comment: Also may I ask what you tries to do here? It seems that this is code to remove duplicates, am I right? It may be a much simpler way for this, but you need to give a better description then.

Comment: I am mapping the cells of an unstructured mesh (with Nc cells) onto a regular mesh (with NSCX*NSCY cells). Why is size(IA,3) = 9? I have said that there will be a maximum of 8 unstructured cells in any regular cell. Does that help?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. Can you elaborate.

Comment: See my answer, if something is unclear please comment under the question. I gave a more wide sense answer since the conditions for cells +8 samples cells are not stated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you should consider another way to go here. you should look at the function `histc` which finds the first value where the sample is larger that previous and smaller than the next sample. For you this can be done for each dimension. This will give you and index for each unsorted cell. I do not know what conditions applying for the +8 inhabitated cells, but I guess that the conditions can be applied after the sorting.

Example of `histc` in 1 dimension

```
a = [1 5 7 12];
b = 2:2:16;
[c,d] = histc(a,b)
```

d gives the index of b in which each a belongs and c is a logic of all non empty indices.

EDIT: Pseudo code for creating a regular meshgrid with `histc`

```
cellX = vector with all regular x centers (or borders?!)
cellY = vector with all regular y centers (or borders)
px = all unstructured x centers
py = all unstructured y centers
[~,xind] = histc(px,cellx); % which cellX does px belong too?
[~,yind] = histc(py,celly); % which cellY does py belong too?
% Code for properly taking care of indices to match wanted format
unstructuredPerStructured = accumarray(indVector, properInd,...) % find number of unstructured cells per structured.
```

I am still not sure of you output since your code is not runable and does not follow the wanted input/output standard of stack exchange, but this seems to be a good approach.

EDIT: Application of histc()

I have attempted to do something like you suggest but I'm not able to replicate the results of my previous code. I've posted the variables needed to run the code [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4gtm3dobbksl78p/sample.mat).

```
NSCX = 20;
NSCY = 20;

cellX = reshape(Xsdc,numel(Xsdc),1);% vector with all regular x centers (or borders?!)
cellY = reshape(Ysdc,numel(Xsdc),1);% vector with all regular y centers (or borders)
px = eince(:,1);% all unstructured x centers
py = eince(:,2);% all unstructured y centers

[y1,i1] = sort(cellX);
[y2,i2] = sort(cellY);

[~,xind] = histc(px,y1); % which cellX does px belong too?
[~,yind] = histc(py,y2); % which cellY does py belong too?

xindrevert = i1(xind);
yindrevert = i2(yind);

for i = 1:Nc
    [a,b] = find(cellX == cellX(xindrevert(i)));
    [c,d] = find(cellY == cellY(yindrevert(i)));
    index = c.*NaN;
    for j = 1:length(c)
        check = a(a == c(j))';
        if ~isempty (check)
            index(j) = check;
        end
    end
    output(i) = index(~isnan(index));
end
unstructuredPerStructured = accumarray(output',1,[NSCX*NSCY,1]); % find number of unstructured cells per structured
unstructuredPerStructured = reshape(unstructuredPerStructured,NSCX,NSCY);
```

unstructuredPerStructured should equal IA(:,:,1), but does not. Can you see the issue? I'm guessing the difference is due to taking the cell centres.

Comment: Can you put together some pseudo code showing your best guess at how histc() would apply here. Not sure I see where to apply histc().

Comment: Ok I have added an example in pseudo code look above. `histc` is a mex file, so it should be much faster then the for loops in matlab. All information about indices should be here and you do just need to combine it right to get what you need. I have left out index handlig since I do not know exact format, but that should be easy for you.

Comment: Hi, I assumed that you solved the issue since you accepted the answer, your code looks as if it will work, just check for bugs and everything will work fine I think, however I think that the the for loops in the last piece of code could be removed as well. But the already made changes should speed up the code a lot

Comment: I haven't managed to match the output of the previous code. I accepted the answer since your suggestion seems to have the right idea. Small details need to be realised to get things to match. Thanks for your help.